# Using AsyncTask With a Observer based Controller class (MVC Arch.)

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, android-asynctask, observer-pattern

I've been following [this tutorial](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2014/02/mvc-applied-on-android-practical.html).
Now, I have to fetch and parse some JSON from a web URL. For that I am thinking to use an AsyncTask for now (might try something else as well. Such as a separate thread. advice..?)

But am not able to decide and approach things for now as to how the AsyncTask can inform back to the controller about the state of execution (I thought of using a handler but that'll defeat the purpose of already used controller acting as a Observer for button click(s)..starting the AsyncTask as well) and where can I put the AsyncTask. Certainly not in the controller itself. As the controller has the sole responsibility of giving out commands/judging + it'll be a cluster f* :D

Any help in form of sample code clearly showing me how/what to accomplish is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show some (pseudo) code of the part you're having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a simplified Observer pattern to your AsyncTask also. Here, your Controller becomes the Observer and AsyncTask will be the notifier. In your onPostExeccute of the AsyncTask, you notify your observers with the result. In your Controller, implement the update method and take action on the result.

Since usually AsyncTask needs to notify only one object, I follow the simpler Listener interface. Define a simple interface with a method called handleResult which takes appropriate data structure. My activity implements this interface (but in your case, it would be the controller) and adds code to handle the result. My AsyncTask stores this listener as a field and on completion of the task, calls the handleResult method.

But as you can see, it is very similar.